# Redirect scp output that matches pattern

Tags: bash, grep, scp

I want redirect output from scp into a file, but only lines that match a pattern. For example, I'm getting a lot of permission denied errors, so I want to log all the files where that is the case. I found that I can redirect all output of scp into a file like this:

```
source my_scp_script.sh > output.log 2>&1
```

The script is just a simple call to scp. I'm stuck on how I can match a pattern like "Permission Denied" and only write those lines to the file, not everything since there are thousands of files that are successful.

EDIT: I forgot to clarify that I have tried using grep, but it does not work when doing it like this `source my_scp_script.sh | grep Permission > output.log`

Comment: Do you know `grep`?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=unix+how+I+can+match+a+pattern. But I see you tagged your question with `grep` so you already know it exists and could google some examples so I can't imagine why you're asking this question.

Comment: Yea I should have clarified grep is not working with scp. I tried piping the output of scp to grep but it didn't work. To get it to even log to a file doesn't work either unless I included the `2>&1` which I don't really know what means either, I just found it on this site. Maybe I can use grep but I'm doing something wrong

Comment: You can still edit your question and add that clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing special about `scp`; you just need to get familiar with shell I/O [redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html).
(*The Linux Documentation Project's* [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/index.html) is IMO a great resource of information; [§20 I/O Redirection](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) contains a nice summary.)

---

You could use `source my_scp_script.sh 1> /tmp/stdout 2> /tmp/stderr` to redirect the output written to the file descriptors `1` (aka *stdout*; note that `1>` can also be written as `>`, which is more commonly used) and `2` (aka *stderr)* to temporary files. You can then inspect `/tmp/std{out,err}` and will find that the *Permission Denied* errors are written to *stderr.*

A simple [pipeline](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html) `| grep` connects *stdout* with `grep`'s *stdin*,
but as you need to connect *stderr*, you can use

```bash
source my_scp_script.sh 2>&1 | grep "Permission Denied" > output.log
```

to redirect file descriptor `2` to file descriptor `1` *before* piping the combined *stdout* to `grep`.

With `|&` being a shortcut for `2>&1 |`, you can finally simplify this to:

```bash
source my_scp_script.sh |& grep "Permission Denied" > output.log
```